# phpMyAdmin not loading correctly

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've installed the LAMPP stack on Linux. Everything is working fine, except for phpMyAdmin.

When I call for localhost/phpMyAdmin, the page won't load after the header. This is the result after calling phpMyAdmin:

[image]

I installed it via the command line:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json php-curl
```

by following the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04

I also tried installing via the Ubuntu graphical package store, but I get the same result with both methods.

Comment: Does network tab shows any errors?

Comment: Did you try with another browser?

Comment: I've tested in other browser: brave. same.

Comment: Network looks ok. screen capture:
https://coinfrs.xyz/stack/errors/pag1.png, and:
https://coinfrs.xyz/stack/errors/pag2.png

Comment: Go check what the web server & PHP error log have to say.

Comment: Could you please tell us the phpMyAdmin and PHP versions you're using here? Which webserver are you using? By the way, https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu has some more information about using phpMyAdmin with the Debian and Ubuntu package managers across various distribution versions.